# MongoDB: Update 1 field in each document in a collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection that consist of many documents but I want to update a single field that is currently a string to a ISODate object.

```
Collection = { 
   { _id: ObjectId('1'), date: '2022-01-01T01:00:00.000Z' },
   ...
};
```

What I am looking for

```
Collection = { 
   { _id: ObjectId('1'), date: ISODate('2022-01-01T01:00:00.000Z') },
   ...
};
```

I figured I could go do a `db.get('Collection').find({}).forEach(... update logic);` but I am unsure how I would set that up.

I appreciate any type of help

EDIT: I figured it out after receiving some help

```
db.getCollection('Collection').find({"date": { "$exists": true, "$type": 2 }}).forEach(function (doc) {
    var newDate = new Date(doc.date);
    db.getCollection('Collection').findAndModify({query: { "_id": doc._id }, update: {
        $set: {
            "date" : newDate
        }
    }})
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do `find().forEach()` because it's going to cause you to stream all of the data to the client and then back.

Instead, just issue an update that can be executed on the server by itself. The general approach is documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/#modify-a-field-using-the-values-of-the-other-fields-in-the-document). For your specific situation you want something like this:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      date: {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: "$date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [playground example here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yn9qx90nQVM).

Comment: Ah the example was good to see how that worked. Thank you. But I might have made a mistake, what if my collection was a JSON object instead of a array. Would it be any different? I'm fairly new working with mongoDB

Comment: Can you update your question with the additional details including sample input and desired output?

Comment: I am using Robo3t to manage my DB, but I made the change. This is the error I am getting 'BSON field 'update.updates.u' is the wrong type 'array', expected type 'object''

Comment: What version of Robo3t and what version is the database? The [aggregation pipeline syntax for updates](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.update/) was introduced in version `4.2`. I can't speak to if/when Robo3t was updated to support it. Assuming your database is at least `4.2`, then you could try upgrading Robo3t, using the shell mode inside of it, or using other tools like Compass or the MongoDB shell to issue the update.

Comment: I'll have to play around a bit. We are on 1.4 of Robo3T and 3.4.2 for Mongo. But I think I have a good start to getting it resolved. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Unfortunately if the source cluster is older than `4.2` then you may have to stream the data back to the client to make the change that you're after... If you do pursue that route be sure to use bulk writes.